# What would be trade off of using dynamic programming in three sum problem?

Tags: data-structures

- I tried writing top down recursion approach and able to solve it. This solution gives TLE while running on leetcode. So I decided to write code in bottom up approach tabulation approach, that I am unable to figured out.

```
void findTriplets(vector<int>& nums, int target, int index, int count, vector<int>& triplet, vector<vector<int>>& result) {
    int last_low = nums[index];
    while(index < nums.size() && nums[index] == last_low) {
        index++;
    }

    if (count == 3) {
        if (target == 0) {
            result.push_back(triplet);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (index >= nums.size()) {
        return;
    }

    // Include current number in the triplet
    triplet.push_back(nums[index]);
    
    findTriplets(nums, target - nums[index], index + 1, count + 1, triplet, result);
    triplet.pop_back(); // Backtrack

    // Exclude current number from the triplet
    findTriplets(nums, target, index + 1, count, triplet, result);
}
```

can someone help me to get the bottom up approach.

Comment: This question is a bit subjective and doesn't really have an objective answer. Therefore, it's not fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Before I jump onto your code, let me explain the thought process before dynamic programming is used.

1. Is there a recursive algorithm that I can use?
2. In my recursive algorithm, is there a chance that I am asking for a subproblem again?
3. Am I reducing my runtime from exponential to polynomial?

Only then would you be ok implementing DP based solution. In the case of your question, even though you are trying to frame the solution that way(point 1), it fails at point 2 and 3. You are not reusing a sub-problem and definitely not reducing the time complexity.

Using 3 for loops results in O(n^3) and your code too results in O(n^3). As an interviewer, I would be disinterested in such an approach as it is hard to read.

Let me give you some good resources for solving this problem.

[Algorithms by Princeton on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/home/week/1)

[DP patterns leetcode](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/458695/Dynamic-Programming-Patterns)

[Algorithm with O(N^2 * logN)](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/)

[leetcode solution video](https://player.vimeo.com/video/842873305)